# AngularJS Form is not in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS Validation in order to validate a simple form, however I was having troubles getting my `ng-class` to show the correct class based off whether or not the `input` was dirty or not. Then when I looked at the actual HTML of the page, the `<form>` tags are not even in the document at all!

```
<form novalidate name="infoForm">
            <p>To start, provide some basic information about the project.</p>

                <ul class="ulFormGeneral">
                    <li>
                        <label>Company name</label>
                        <input id="CompanyName" ng-class="{ cvError : infoForm.CompanyName.$dirty }" ng-model="form.CompanyName" name="CompanyName" maxlength="100" type="text" required />
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </form>
```

I want the `cvError` class to be added to this `input` if it is dirty, but nothing happens when I look at this in the browser. What am I doing wrong that is causing the `<form>` to just leave the DOM and then not work with my Angular expressions?

Comment: Can you upload a fiddle with this issue? looks legit..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Angular world, no forms required! Here, the model is king. It looks like the problem is the `ng-model` and `ng-class` are point at different places.

Point everything at `form.CompanyName` (assuming that is the model name is *form* in the $scope):

```
<input id="CompanyName" ng-class="{ cvError : form.CompanyName.$dirty }" ng-model="form.CompanyName" name="CompanyName" maxlength="100" type="text" required />
```

The [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) binds to the [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). When you change the input field, it is automatically updated in the $scope. No form is needed or hitting a submit button to get the data. The $scope is updated with each key stroke.

The [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) should do the work of figuring out what to do with the changes in the model. For example, you can add an [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to a button that fires a function defined by the controller to save the model.

Comment: I completely understand the 2-way binding. I guess I just didn't know that Angular takes out your `<form>` tags. Still have no idea why `infoForm` is not defined when I try to print `infoForm.CompanyName.$valid`

Comment: Angular does not do anything special to the <form> tag. As far as it is concerned, it is just normal markup.

Comment: That's not correct. To access "form.CompanyName" you need "form" to be your *form* name, not the model name in the $scope.

Comment: @MattHintzke, you should still use form wherever it's needed, both for semantic purposes and to be able to use better validation checks

Comment: well I have `$scope.form` in my controller to control that data in the form. Sorry if that confused you. But I still cannot access the form validation properties like `$dirty, $valid, $invalid, etc`